# cannot set text attribute of asp.net button in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having problem here, I can get the '`Text`' of asp.net button by using '`val()`' in jQuery, but could not set the 'Text' in any way. I have tried '`attr`','`prop`','`val()`','`text()`' and '`html()`'. Please help.

JavaScript

```
$("#<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>").attr('text', 'hello');
var sh = $("#<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>").val();
alert(sh);
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server"  onclick="hiddenButton_Click" Text="NORTH EAST FESTIVAL" />
```

The alert box still shows "NORTH EAST FESTIVAL".

my html is inside a content placeholder, which is inside a form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `.val()` to set the value instead of setting the attribute:

```
$("#<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>").val('hello');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. but in the code behind, I am still getting the old 'Text' value. How to make the new value reflect in the code behind too?

Comment: When are you fetching the value in code behind?? you should fetch it once changes are done via jquery.

Comment: after successfully changing the 'text' in the mentioned method I am calling the 'click()' method in jquery, so the event handler of this asp.net button executes. There I am fetching the 'Text', but still getting the default text that I entered at design time

Comment: Is this new 'Text' value maintained after postback?

Comment: Any way I can retrieve this new value after postback?

Comment: Thanks this way I can retrieve this value after post back. But when I use it as a string in a path to navigate to a folder(name of the folder was retrieve here), an error occurs saying "Illegal characters in path.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path."

Comment: @SudiptaBhattacharyya: i am sure you will get the solution if you google the exception.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Just felt too lazy to do that. I'll inform if I can find the solution. :)

Comment: Sir, the string returned was padded with "\r\n" and white spaces. So I used string.Replace() and string.Trim() functions. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks for taking out time to help me. Hope others can benefit from this post :)

Comment: @SudiptaBhattacharyya: glad everything worked correctly.